# how to customize heatmap highcharts plot area and the color of the datalabels

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

Would love some help here with highcharts,i have attached  an image i want to accomplish 2 things here

**First:** Is it possible to place the data of the yAxis in this case a day between 2 plotlines and the datalabel in between those 2 lines instead of getting crossed in the middle by it? For example i want the 30th of April under that line and the datalabel above that line as well positioned according to the day

**Second:** How can i change the color of the numbers to black when the color is that light green, it makes it hard to read.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set `yAxis.type` as category and use formatter to imitate dates.
2. Use `dataLabels.formatter` to change a color depending on a point value.

   ```
   series: [{
       ...,
       dataLabels: {
           enabled: true,
           formatter: function() {
               if (this.color === '#FF00FF') {
                   return '<span style="color: orange">' + this.y + '</span>';
               }

               return this.y;
           }
       }
   }],
   yAxis: {
       type: 'category'
   }
   ```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qxfa9b0c/1/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.type

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.dataLabels.formatter